# How to embed gif in discord's rich embed? like hug, kiss commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in using discord.py but I don't know how to send gifs in an embed. I'm trying to make commands like hug, kiss , boop etc. How would I do this?

````
          embed1 = discord.Embed(title="this is a title", description="this is a description!", color=0x00ff00,)
        await message.channel.send(embed = embed1)```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your question to include an example of the code you are currently working on? That would help others to give a tailored answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `set_image()` function passing an url to your image to set the embed image to the one you want.

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description", color=0x00ff00)
embed.add_field(name="Field1", value="test", inline=False)
embed.set_image(url="https://url-to-your-picture.gif")
await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

References:

- [Embed class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed)
- [Embed.set_image()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.set_image)

Comment: Can you also tell how to show which user is doing the action to which user? and thank you very much

Comment: Well if your command is something like `!kiss @user123`, you can retrieve one user from the command itself (passing it as expected parameter in the function definition) and the other from `ctx.message.author`.

Comment: So ```message.author.name``` will do it? I am new to all this 

Comment: Yes, the other you can get it by declaring your function something like `async def kiss(self, ctx, user: discord.Member):` and it would be `user.name`

Comment: You can put it in the title or the description, that is up to you.